# Error in postgresql function

Tags: postgresql

Explain me please, why I'm getting error here:

```
djabase=# CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION upset(domain_name varchar)
RETURNS TABLE (id int, domain varchar(50)) AS $$
BEGIN
SELECT domain from separser_domains where domain=$1;
EXCEPTION
when sqlstate 'no_data' then
INSERT into separser_domains(domain) VALUES (domain_name);
END; $$
LANGUAGE 'sql' STABLE;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 4: SELECT domain from separser_domains where domain=$1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using PLPGSQL syntax but declaring the function as SQL. This the reason, why the function fails with a `SYNTAX ERROR`. The language of the function is declared with the statement `LANGUAGE` and you declared it in the last line:

```
LANGUAGE 'sql' STABLE;
```

SQL functions do not support the `BEGIN` - `END` statement and exceptions trapping.

To fix it, simple change `LANGUAGE 'sql'` in `LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'`.

Some other considerations:

- Catching a exception in this place is probably not necessary. Use the FOUND variable instead.
- With the `STABLE` keyword, the function can not perform `INSERT`. Change `STABLE`to `VOLATILE`.
- You declared `RETURNS TABLE` but the function does not return anything. Use `RETURNS VOID` instead.
- Using `SELECT` and discarding the result is not allowed. Use `PERFORM` instead.

A valid version of your version could be this:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS upset(varchar);
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION upset(domain_name varchar)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
  BEGIN
    PERFORM domain from separser_domains where domain=domain_name;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
      INSERT into separser_domains(domain) VALUES (domain_name);
    END IF;
    RETURN;
  END; 
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```